# Apply each function from a list to a corresponding column on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am currently trying to apply a series on functions stored within a list to a data-frame with the same number of columns as there are functions, as to apply each function to it's column equivalent.

For example, in this case I have a data-frame with 5 columns and each column must have their data validated according to some specification. Thus I have the following example data set:

```
>my_data
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  `Payee Name` `SAP Vendor #` Amount `Invoice Date` `Invoice #`
  <chr>        <chr>          <chr>  <chr>          <chr>
1 X COMPANY   134            65.64  11/16/2019     89724404
2 X COMPANY   134            197.68 11/15/2019     89724470
3 X COMPANY   134            247.63 11/15/2019     89724300
4 X COMPANY   134            215.34 11/14/2019     89579028
```

And to validate them I have the following functions declared and saved into a list

```
payee_name <- function(a){grepl("^[\\w &-]+$", perl = TRUE, a)}
vendor_no <- function(a){grepl("^\\d{3}$", perl = TRUE, a)}
amount <- function(a){grepl("^-?\\d+\\.\\d{2}$", perl= TRUE, a)}
date_val <- function(a){
    grepl(
        paste(
            # Month validation
            "(0[1-9]|1[012])",
            # Day validation
            "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])",
            # Year validation
            "(19[6-9][0-9]|20[0-9]{2})",
            # / required by format as separator
            sep = "/"
        ),
        a
    )
}
invoice_val <- function(a){grepl("^\\d{8}$", perl = TRUE, a)}

fun_lst <- list(
  payee_name,
  vendor_no,
  amount,
  date_val,
  invoice_val
)
```

I want to obtain a logical data-frame/matrix which contains TRUE/FALSE depending on the results of the tested columns. So far the way I have been doing so has been to create a matrix of the same dimensions as the original data-frame filled with NAs and then replacing the columns with the results using sapply:

```
my_data_results <- matrix(NA, nrow(my_data), ncol(my_data))
colnames(my_data_results) <- colnames(my_data)

for(i in 1:ncol(my_data)){
  my_data_results[,i] <- sapply(my_data[,i], fun_lst[[i]])
}
```

I believe there might be a better way to do this, as I want to scale this to also work with data-frames which are nested into lists and currently it is becoming a hassle to do so.

Comment: `mydata[] <- Map(function(f,x) f(x), fun_lst, my_data)` might work.

Comment: This does seem to fit my use case if I turn it into a tibble in the following manner 
`as_tibble(Map(function(f,x) f(x), fun_lst, my_data, .name_repair = function(x) colnames(my_data))`
Expanding a bit on the original question, how could I make it work with dataframes/tibbles within a list?

Comment: `lapply(list_of_frames, function(dat) Map(function(f,x) f(x), fun_lst, dat))` might work, assuming that all frames are structured the same.